# XSL-FO : Image doesn't show in PDF File

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

this is my problem : my image doesn't show in my PDF file.

this is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Devis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mon_fichier.xsd">
    <EnTete>
        <Logo>
            <img>file:/C:/mon_fichier.jpg</img>
        </Logo>
</EnTete>
</Devis>
```

This is my XSL File :

```
<xsl:template match="/">

...
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before"
                    font-size="12pt" font-family="Times New Roman">
        <fo:block>
         <xsl:param name="image" select="EnTete/Logo/img" />

         <fo:external-graphic src="{concat('url','(',$image,')')}"
            content-height="80px" content-width="640px" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

...

</xsl:template>
```

Any ideas ?

thank you in advance.

FM

Comment: When you process the XML file, what does the external-graphic statement in the resulting FO file look like?

Comment: the result is a simple image to insert to the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few points that you should check:

- the *xsl:param* declaration is not in a valid position, it should be right after the *xsl:template*; if you never actually pass a value to the template and always use the selected one, you could use *xsl:variable* instead, and put it wherever you want
- the XPath should be `Devis/EnTete/Logo/img` (or `/Devis/EnTete/Logo/img`, or `//EnTete/Logo/img`) if you want to select the image pathname in a template matching "/"
- you don't mention what formatter you are using; if it's a recent version of Apache FOP, you don't have to put the image path inside `url(...)`, just use `<fo:external-graphic src="{$image}" content-height="80px" content-width="640px"/>`
- the image pathname in the XML file should probably be: **file://C:/mon_fichier.jpg** (with **//** instead of a single **/**)

Answer (score 0):

The path in your XML is strange: file:/C:/mon_fichier.jpg should be C:\mon_fichier.jpg

And then this should work:

```
fo:external-graphic src="/Devis/EnTete/Logo/img"
```

The xsl:param in your XSL does nothing. Why is it there?